# List comprehension with if-condition

Tags: python, optimization, coding-style

The following line of Python code

```
values = ", ".join(["\"%s\"" % x for x in row])
```

takes a list of elements in "row" to create a comma-separated string "values", while each value is put in double quotes, e.g.:
"New York", "5", "", "3.2"

However, since the result is to be part of a mysqldump file, empty fields ("") should become NULL (without double quotes).

Therefore, I'd like to learn how to change that expression so that it is checked whether x is empty (""), in which case NULL should be appended to the values string.

Thanks

Comment: FYI: you don't need to use the `[]` and a list comprehension.  If you leave them out, then what's left is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
values = ", ".join(["NULL" if x == "" else "\"%s\"" % x for x in row])
```

Comment: This solution also works but is a bit less elegant than Tim's.

Comment: They do different things. Tim's `if x` will also print `NULL` for `x == 0`, which may not be what Steve06 intended.

Comment: Your comment is spot on, just test it and can confirm. This makes your solution the winner.

Answer (score 7):

```
values = ", ".join('"%s"' % x if x else 'NULL' for x in row)
```

For example:

```
>>> row = ["foo", "", "bar"]
>>> values = ", ".join('"%s"' % x if x else 'NULL' for x in row)
>>> values
'"foo", NULL, "bar"'
```

Thanks to DSM for pointing out that it's of course even better to change the list comprehension into a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) - this makes it faster because it's no longer necessary to construct a list that will be discarded immediately afterwards.

Comment: Short and sweet solution, thanks a lot! Besides providing a solution, it teaches me how to nest code in Python and how priorities are handled. Danke!

Comment: Note that this will output `NULL` for any falsy value of `x`, not just the empty string `""`: `0` and `0.0` and `[]` and `{}` will all result in `NULL`.

Comment: I find that the genexp is actually a little slower here, but that's often the case with very small examples.  Eventually the genexp will win.

Comment: I've posted an answer using `csv` that's a bit convoluted, but I guess this will work with `values = ', '.join('"%s"' % str(x).replace('"', '""') ...` to handle embedded quotes

Answer (score 0):

To make this a bit more robust, I'd utilise the `csv` module to handle embedded field and string delimiters... (just an adhoc example)

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import csv

csvrec = StringIO()
csvout = csv.writer(csvrec, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
items = [1, 'hello, there, how are you?', 3.2, 'it\'s a "cat" I say!', '', '']
csvout.writerow([col or '\t' for col in items]) # maybe col != '' ?
print csvrec.getvalue().replace('"\t"', 'NULL').strip()
# "1","hello, there, how are you?","3.2","it's a ""cat"" I say!",NULL,NULL
```